# Function gets printed twice

Tags: php, arrays, function, foreach, echo

I made this function, the same result get printed twice. Any idea why? is it my function? I can't find anything wrong with it.

$valid is an array.

```
function validOutput($output, $valid, $name, $mirror){
                foreach($valid as $e) {
                    if(strpos($output, $e) != false) {
                        echo '<br />' . $name . '<br />';
                        echo '<textarea cols=100 rows=10>';
                        echo '[tab: Mirror' . $mirror . ']';
                        echo $output;
                        echo "</textarea>"; 
                    }
                }
}
```

Please tell me if you see anything wrong with it, thanks.

Edit:

```
$valid = array("facebook", "fbcdn", "megavideo", "video", "videoweed", "4shared");
```

Comment: what is the content of `$valid` ?

Comment: no way to know from this code where problem actually is but either you are putting dupe info in $valid or else you are calling validOutput() twice

Comment: @crayon Violet "dupe info in $valid" That was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$valid` has two elements that are substrings of `$output`

Can you show some sample inputs?  Maybe explain what the motivation behind the `$valid` parameter is?

Comment: @jon_darkstar Figured it out, it was "video" occurring twice. Thanks :)

Comment: i still dont really get the motivation for what you're doing, not that i need to.  you want to print that stuff once for every element of `$valid` that is not a part of `$output`?  if its doing what you want then fantastic, i just dont understnad

Comment: @jon_darkstar Nope, but I want to print stuff that has strings from $valid, if that made any sense.

Comment: ooo i misread the `!=` it will do as you say, but the output doesnt feature any part of `$e` so it will simply be repeated.  the outputs wont be any different from each other.

Comment: @jon_darkstar This is in a while function where $output[$i] :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that could be the problem, but `strpos()` must be checked as `=== false` or `!== false`, because `strpos` could be `0` and it will be treated as `false`.

Doc > http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: Ah I see, somehow the code works just fine. I'll correct it anyway. Thank you.